# Is it OK to reuse the same SALT key across multiple deployments?

Tags: aes, salt

We are building a base application that needs to encrypt SSN, DOB, etc...

The application is deployed to many customers.

Is it "OK" to use the same SALT key for the AES encryption/decryption ?

Comment: generally every entry should always have a unique salt

Comment: Yup it's totally okay.

But then it stops being a salt.

And also stops offering the protection of one.

Comment: @Iszi *meh*, it still prevents entries from being decrypted with password lists if the user used a popular password like `password123` (assuming that salt is still unknown at this point). So it's probably just a little bit better than nothing at all but it's definitely not the best way.

Comment: It works until the attacker realizes that your application is deployed to multiple customers with the same salt. Then they'll build the database, and the value of the salt is effectively negated.

Comment: When your salt value is a constant, it's called a "pepper".

Comment: It seems that you are talking about encryption (two way), then you need an IV not a salt. Both salt and IV should be unique and should **not** be reused.

Answer (score 4):

You write *Salt*, but your examples include recoverable data and you mention an encryption algorithm: AES. Salt is usually added to hashes to prevent collisions and undercut the value of rainbow tables, as mentioned in other answers. However, the other answers all discuss passwords, while you appear to be protecting recoverable data (SSN, DOB, etc.).  Hashes, salting, password verifiers and rainbow tables don't apply.

Instead, you should use an IV (Initial Vector) with block-based symmetric ciphers and CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) to prevent the same class of attack that a Salt protects against: known plaintext attack of cryptographic material.

For example, Mary and John have the same birthdate (e.g. May 1, 1984). If you have one Master Key to encrypt all of the data, and you don't use random IVs, then anyone with access to the cryptext in the database can see that `ENC(Mary_BDATE, Key) == ENC(John_BDATE, Key)`.

However, with unique random IVs, then `ENC(Mary_BDATE, Key, IV1) != ENC(John_BDATE, Key, IV2)`. Here, the IV (like a Salt) is stored with the cryptext in the clear, it need not be kept secret.

Incidentally, you can get the same effect of a unique IV by prepending the plain text data with a Nonce of size Block. That is, `ENC(Nonce1||Mary_BDATE, Key) != ENC(Nonce2||John_BDATE, Key)`. In this case, when you decrypt, you discard the prepended Nonce. There's no need to store it as it's the first Block in the cryptext.

Note, in either of the above cases, the storage requirement is essentially the same: IV and Nonce lengths should be equal and both are the same length as the Block size. There's some benefit to using an IV over prepending the Nonce as the plaintext from the Decrypt step requires no manipulation.

Also, you really ought to use unique IVs for all of your data, even if you believe the data might be unique (say in the case of SSN). First off, the SSN is a relatively small range of values, so there aren't a lot of choices for the plaintext being encrypted. More importantly, because the length of plaintext is so small, there might be some known key compromise attacks on such a small field. Generally, symmetric block ciphers are built to resist these types of attacks. However, when the data is all less than (and much less than) a block length, there's only so much the cipher can do.  By adding a random IV, you spread the encryption across two blocks **and** you add more entropy to the cryptext. This makes known plaintext attack and various key attacks harder.

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT okay.

Someone can get your salt, build a rainbow table, and easily decrypt all data from all customers. The whole point of a salt is to negate the effects of rainbow tables.

You shouldn't even use the same salt with one customers. Just generate a new salt with every new key. You can store the encrypted text and salt together, there is no need to protect the salt.

Comment: You wrote store "key and salt" together, don't you mean "*crypt text* and salt"?

Comment: Yes you're right, I edited it

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an example of why you should use different salts for each entry in a common scenario of an attacker getting at your database.

---

Say I'm some attacker who just got ahold of your database. Since you, the security conscious developer, hashed all of the passwords, it should be difficult for the attacker to get the passwords and give the users enough time to change their passwords right?

Not so! I happened to have a rather large collection of precomputed hashes for entries length `n` chars to `n + k` chars (GBs and GBs of data.. takes a long time to produce this once) and will try all of the different users against them.

You saw this coming and decided to use a salt on all of the entries for password hashing even though it's the same salt.

No matter, I will spend a lot of time attempting to bruteforce the password for 1 user and after a couple of days or weeks (can be less if you use the top 1,000 popular passwords and only bruteforce the salt value) of trying different passwords i get this: `mysaltp@ssw0rd`. I now recompute my hashtable with `mysalt` at the start of each entry (this only takes about as long as the first time i computed my hashtable). I will then proceed to find the password for any user who used a password of length `n` to `n + k` characters.

---

If you use a different salt for each, i have to recalculate every single password combination between `n` chars and `n + k` chars with the hash appended to it which takes **significantly** longer. Additionally, one rotten egg (the user who happened to use `password1234` as their password) won't spoil the bunch and make it that much easier to get at the passwords.